# react-native logInWithReadPermissions not calling safari sometimes, no error thrown, handle (callback) not called

Tags: react-native, facebook-login

I am using FBSDKLoginManager to log in with facebook manually.
I have created a native method in which I have the following code:

```
#import "FacebookLoginManager.h"
#import "FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h"
#import "FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h"

@implementation FacebookLoginManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(newSession:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {


  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];


  [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email"] fromViewController: nil handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
      callback(@[@"Error", [NSNull null]]);
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
      callback(@[@"Canceled", [NSNull null]]);
    } else {
      FBSDKAccessToken *token = result.token;
      NSString *tokenString = token.tokenString;
      NSString *userId = token.userID;
      NSDictionary *credentials = @{ @"token" : tokenString, @"userId" : userId };
      callback(@[[NSNull null], credentials]);
    }
  }];

    });

};
```

The code works mostly but sometimes it does not trigger the login window (safari) although it does not throw any error. 
Besides, the handler code is never called in this case. If I close the app and reopen it everything works again.

The problem happens after a period of time passes so I suspect it may be related to some timeout or token expiration somewhere but I am not sure.

How can I fix this problem, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that revoking the facebook access token on logout solved the problem. Perhaps the FBSDKLoginManager had some problems when the user had already authorized your app and you try to ask for authorization again.
To revoke the token I make a remote call to my server which has facebook's PHP SDK:

```
<?php
    $fb = new Facebook(array(
                        'app_id'                => 'YOUR_FB_APP_ID',
                        'app_secret'            => 'YOUR_FB_APP_SECRET',
                        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
                        ));

                        try 
                        {
                            $userFbToken     = 'user-fb-token-stored-somewhere';
                            $appsecret_proof = hash_hmac('sha256', $userFbToken, 'YOUR_FB_APP_SECRET'); 
                            $response        = $fb->delete("/me/permissions", array('appsecret_proof'=>$appsecret_proof),$userFbToken);
                        }
                        catch(FacebookResponseException $e) 
                        {
                           // exception handling...
                        }
```